# sent btc to my bch address

Tags: bitcoin-cash

OK so I have a wallet on Blockchain.info. It is able to receive btc bch and eth coins. My friend sent me some btc but I accidently gave him the bch address. Am I screwed? Can the btc arrive in the wallet through a bch address?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to get these Bitcoins back. since the bitcoins sent to an address on another network. and nobody has the private key of this address.

Comment: That's not true, because Blockchain.info has them, but their support is either unwilling or unable to retrieve them. Just check the dozens of other similar questions here on SE.

Comment: This is a big charge against blockchain. because they claim they are using client-side encryption, its open source project and nobody ever has access to private keys.

Comment: I suppose my comment may be false. Coinbase is known for being able to retrieve private keys in these cases. maybe blockchain.info is truly unable to do that.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to recover as long as you control the key.